# iPhone SDK 4.3 libav compiling problem

Tags: iphone, libav, iphone-sdk-4.3

I faced with strange problem. I installed iPhone SDK 4.3 and xCode 4 and now I can't compile libav from ffmpeg for ARMv6 architecture. This is my script to compile it (it works fine for iPhone SDK 4.2):

```
./configure \
--disable-doc --disable-ffmpeg --disable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-cross-compile \
--enable-encoder=rawvideo \
--enable-decoder=h264 \
--enable-decoder=mpeg4 \
--enable-encoder=mjpeg \
--enable-muxer=rawvideo \
--enable-demuxer=h264 \
--enable-parser=h264 \
--enable-cross-compile \
--arch=c \
--target-os=darwin \
--enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 \
--as='gas-preprocessor/gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer    /usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1' \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk \
--cpu=arm1176jzf-s --extra-cflags='-arch armv6' --extra-ldflags='-arch armv6'

make clean
make
```

as a result I get library files but when I check it with lipo -info command it shows that library was compiled for i386 architecture.

Maybe somebody faced with such problem? Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Somebody faced with problem of compiling of ffmpeg under iOS SDK 4.3?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Updated Post**

Here is an updated script that removes armv6, adds armv7s, uses the iOS 6.0 SDK, and fixes issues with changes to the `lipo` tool. Make sure you have the latest `gas-preprocessor.pl` from [github](https://github.com/yuvi/gas-preprocessor/blob/master/gas-preprocessor.pl) in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
rm -r ./compiled

# configure for armv7 build
./configure \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk \
--extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system \
--target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=cortex-a8 \
--extra-cflags='-arch armv7' \
--extra-ldflags='-arch armv7' \
--extra-cflags='-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mvectorize-with-neon-quad' \
--prefix=compiled/armv7 \
--enable-pic \
--enable-neon \
--enable-cross-compile \
--enable-optimizations \
--disable-debug \
--disable-armv5te \
--disable-armv6 \
--disable-armv6t2 \
--disable-armvfp \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-doc

# build for armv7
make clean
make && make install

# configure for armv7s build
./configure \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk \
--extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system \
--target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=cortex-a8 \
--extra-cflags='-arch armv7s' \
--extra-ldflags='-arch armv7s' \
--extra-cflags='-mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -mvectorize-with-neon-quad' \
--prefix=compiled/armv7s \
--enable-pic \
--enable-neon \
--enable-cross-compile \
--enable-optimizations \
--disable-debug \
--disable-armv5te \
--disable-armv6 \
--disable-armv6t2 \
--disable-armvfp \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-doc

# build for armv7s
make clean
make && make install

# configure for i386 build
./configure \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk \
--extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/system \
--target-os=darwin \
--arch=i386 \
--cpu=i386 \
--extra-cflags='-arch i386' \
--extra-ldflags='-arch i386' \
--prefix=compiled/i386 \
--enable-cross-compile \
--disable-mmx \
--disable-armv5te \
--disable-armv6 \
--disable-armv6t2 \
--disable-armvfp \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-doc

# build for i386
make clean
make && make install

# make fat (universal) libs
mkdir -p ./compiled/fat/lib

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavcodec.a  -create \
./compiled/armv7s/lib/libavcodec.a \
./compiled/armv7/lib/libavcodec.a \
./compiled/i386/lib/libavcodec.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavdevice.a  -create \
./compiled/armv7s/lib/libavdevice.a \
./compiled/armv7/lib/libavdevice.a \
./compiled/i386/lib/libavdevice.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavfilter.a  -create \
./compiled/armv7s/lib/libavfilter.a \
./compiled/armv7/lib/libavfilter.a \
./compiled/i386/lib/libavfilter.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavformat.a  -create \
./compiled/armv7s/lib/libavformat.a \
./compiled/armv7/lib/libavformat.a \
./compiled/i386/lib/libavformat.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavutil.a  -create \
./compiled/armv7s/lib/libavutil.a \
./compiled/armv7/lib/libavutil.a \
./compiled/i386/lib/libavutil.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libswresample.a  -create \
./compiled/armv7s/lib/libswresample.a \
./compiled/armv7/lib/libswresample.a \
./compiled/i386/lib/libswresample.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libswscale.a  -create \
./compiled/armv7s/lib/libswscale.a \
./compiled/armv7/lib/libswscale.a \
./compiled/i386/lib/libswscale.a
```

**Original Post**

This will build ffmpeg static libraries for armv6, armv7, and i386 architectures and combine them into fat (universal) files for iOS 4.3 (iPhoneOS4.3 and iPhoneSimulator4.3):

```
rm -r ./compiled

# configure for armv7 build
./configure \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk \
--extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/system \
--target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=cortex-a8 \
--extra-cflags='-arch armv7' \
--extra-ldflags='-arch armv7' \
--prefix=compiled/armv7 \
--enable-pic \
--enable-cross-compile \
--disable-armv5te \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-doc

# build for armv7
make clean
make && make install

# configure for armv6 build
./configure \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk \
--extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/system \
--target-os=darwin \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=arm1176jzf-s \
--extra-cflags='-arch armv6' \
--extra-ldflags='-arch armv6' \
--prefix=compiled/armv6 \
--enable-cross-compile \
--disable-armv5te \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-doc

# build for armv6
make clean
make && make install

# configure for i386 build
./configure \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--as='gas-preprocessor.pl /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk \
--extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/system \
--target-os=darwin \
--arch=i386 \
--cpu=i386 \
--extra-cflags='-arch i386' \
--extra-ldflags='-arch i386' \
--prefix=compiled/i386 \
--enable-cross-compile \
--disable-armv5te \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffserver \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-doc

# build for i386
make clean
make && make install

# make fat (universal) libs
mkdir -p ./compiled/fat/lib

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavcodec.a  -create \
-arch armv6 ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavcodec.a \
-arch armv7 ./compiled/armv7/lib/libavcodec.a \
-arch i386 ./compiled/i386/lib/libavcodec.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavdevice.a  -create \
-arch armv6 ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavdevice.a \
-arch armv7 ./compiled/armv7/lib/libavdevice.a \
-arch i386 ./compiled/i386/lib/libavdevice.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavfilter.a  -create \
-arch armv6 ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavfilter.a \
-arch armv7 ./compiled/armv7/lib/libavfilter.a \
-arch i386 ./compiled/i386/lib/libavfilter.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavformat.a  -create \
-arch armv6 ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavformat.a \
-arch armv7 ./compiled/armv7/lib/libavformat.a \
-arch i386 ./compiled/i386/lib/libavformat.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libavutil.a  -create \
-arch armv6 ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavutil.a \
-arch armv7 ./compiled/armv7/lib/libavutil.a \
-arch i386 ./compiled/i386/lib/libavutil.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libpostproc.a  -create \
-arch armv6 ./compiled/armv6/lib/libpostproc.a \
-arch armv7 ./compiled/armv7/lib/libpostproc.a \
-arch i386 ./compiled/i386/lib/libpostproc.a

lipo -output ./compiled/fat/lib/libswscale.a  -create \
-arch armv6 ./compiled/armv6/lib/libswscale.a \
-arch armv7 ./compiled/armv7/lib/libswscale.a \
-arch i386 ./compiled/i386/lib/libswscale.a
```

Comment: Before running the script, you may also want to delete inverse.c from ./libavcodec and remove the reference to inverse.o from ./libavcodec/makefile as inverse.o is compiled into libavutil and will result in a conflict when you include both libs in your project.

Comment: @Anton should this work by just : 

1. cloning git repo from ffmpeg.org

2. making new build file `build_new` and pasting the above code

3. running ./build_new

because i'm experiencing some problems.

Comment: @Anton I'm not getting any *.a files in the /build/armv6/ and /build/armv7/. only in the i386 i get the files so the lipo fail, and therefor it doesn't work.

Comment: @Robin, I just updated with the latest copy of my build script. Try it again.

Comment: @Anton it's still the same :/ dunno why since i just got a fresh clone from the repository and pasted code and changed chmod +x on the file. now i don't even get subfolders for the other archs (just /fat/ and /i386/) in /compiled/. i'll put the output in a file and post it if you would like to take a look.

Comment: @Anton , just brainstorming a bit here, but should it really be make clean between the different make & make install?

Comment: @RobinRye, it doesn't hurt.  I like to make sure that if anything fails, it fails loud.