# fail building ffmpeg for armv6-7

Tags: iphone, ios, ffmpeg, compilation, arm

I've been trying to build ffmpeg in every possible way I can think of. I'm trying with the latest revision from their git repository and with a build script which I have confirmation that it works, it's from this question: [iPhone SDK 4.3 libav compiling problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516170/iphone-sdk-4-3-libav-compiling-problem/6075920#comment-8351950). The script was updated yesterday and apparently works for the guy in the question.

my problem is that it doesn't generate the .a files (or actually any files) for armv6 anc armv7. and therefor the **lipo** commands, to concat into universal libs, fail. I've also tried using the build scripts from [iFrameExtractor](https://github.com/lajos/iFrameExtractor) without any success it also fails with the lipo-commands in the end, i get the following:

```
lipo: can't open input file: ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavcodec.a (No such file or directory)
lipo: can't open input file: ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavdevice.a (No such file or directory)
lipo: can't open input file: ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavfilter.a (No such file or directory)
lipo: can't open input file: ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavformat.a (No such file or directory)
lipo: can't open input file: ./compiled/armv6/lib/libavutil.a (No such file or directory)
lipo: can't open input file: ./compiled/armv6/lib/libpostproc.a (No such file or directory)
lipo: can't open input file: ./compiled/armv6/lib/libswscale.a (No such file or directory)
```

and i have also posted the entire output [here](https://rapidshare.com/files/3444142529/output.txt) if anyone has any idea what to look for there (because i don't know where to start, it almost 5000 lines of output.)
i should also mention that i'm compiling it for **armv6**, **armv7** and **i386**. I want to import it in XCode to get H.264 frames from video feed.

when i try to build for armv6 i use the following configure:

```
./configure \
--enable-cross-compile \
--arch=arm \
--extra-cflags='-arch armv6' \
--extra-ldflags='-arch armv6' \
--target-os=darwin \
--cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
--sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk \
--cpu=arm1176jzf-s \
--extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/usr/lib/system \
--prefix=compiled/armv6
```

and get the following output:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solving the problem.
```

so the question, what c compiler should I use? i've tried different: 
arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1
arm-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 
gcc

but with the same result. gcc works for both i386 and armv7 so i guess it should work for armv6 aswell

Comment: You do know that you can't use FFMPEG for apps that you want to submit to the App Store due to FFMPEG being licensed with LGPL/GPL ?

Comment: @DarkDust yes i know. but i want to compile it anyhow. have any suggestions on what else i can use to retrieve the h.264 frames in real time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem compiling ffmpeg for iFrameExtractor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994151/problem-compiling-ffmpeg-for-iframeextractor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i used the following to compile only for armv6 and armv7. I couldn't get it working for i386, i receive errors that the cputype and subcputype are wrong. apparently the cputype is supposed to be x86 and subcputype should be intel.

anyhow i used the following build scripts to compile (i ended up using gcc and it worked, it was the configure flags that were wrong from the beginning i guess) for the arm architectures:

build script:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

SCRIPT_DIR=$( (cd -P $(dirname $0) && pwd) )
DIST_DIR_BASE=${DIST_DIR_BASE:="$SCRIPT_DIR/dist"}

if [ -d ffmpeg ]
then
  echo "Found ffmpeg source directory, no need to fetch from git..."
else
  echo "Fetching ffmpeg from git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git..."
  git clone git://git.videolan.org/ffmpeg.git
fi

ARCHS=${ARCHS:-"armv6 armv7"}

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
    FFMPEG_DIR=ffmpeg-$ARCH
    if [ -d $FFMPEG_DIR ]
    then
      echo "Removing old directory $FFMPEG_DIR"
      rm -rf $FFMPEG_DIR
    fi
    echo "Copying source for $ARCH to directory $FFMPEG_DIR"
    cp -a ffmpeg $FFMPEG_DIR

    cd $FFMPEG_DIR

    DIST_DIR=$DIST_DIR_BASE-$ARCH
    mkdir -p $DIST_DIR

    case $ARCH in
        armv6)
            EXTRA_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin --arch=arm --cpu=arm1176jzf-s"
            EXTRA_CFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
            EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
            ;;
        armv7)
            EXTRA_FLAGS="--enable-cross-compile --target-os=darwin --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-pic"
            EXTRA_CFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
            EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-arch $ARCH"
            ;;
        x86_64)
            EXTRA_CC_FLAGS="-mdynamic-no-pic"
            ;;
    esac

    echo "Configuring ffmpeg for $ARCH..."
    ./configure \
    --prefix=$DIST_DIR \
    --extra-ldflags=-L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/system \
    --disable-bzlib \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffserver \
    --cc=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc \
    --sysroot=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk \
    --extra-ldflags="$EXTRA_LDFLAGS" \
    --extra-cflags="$EXTRA_CFLAGS" \
    $EXTRA_FLAGS

    echo "Installing ffmpeg for $ARCH..."
    make && make install

    cd $SCRIPT_DIR

    if [ -d $DIST_DIR/bin ]
    then
      rm -rf $DIST_DIR/bin
    fi
    if [ -d $DIST_DIR/share ]
    then
      rm -rf $DIST_DIR/share
    fi
done
```

and combine libs script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

ARCHS="armv6 armv7"

for ARCH in $ARCHS
do
  if [ -d dist-$ARCH ]
  then
    MAIN_ARCH=$ARCH
  fi
done

if [ -z "$MAIN_ARCH" ]
then
  echo "Please compile an architecture"
  exit 1
fi


OUTPUT_DIR="dist-uarch"
rm -rf $OUTPUT_DIR

mkdir -p $OUTPUT_DIR/lib $OUTPUT_DIR/include

for LIB in dist-$MAIN_ARCH/lib/*.a
do
  LIB=`basename $LIB`
  LIPO_CREATE=""
  for ARCH in $ARCHS
  do
    if [ -d dist-$ARCH ]
    then
      LIPO_CREATE="$LIPO_CREATE-arch $ARCH dist-$ARCH/lib/$LIB "
    fi
  done
  OUTPUT="$OUTPUT_DIR/lib/$LIB"
  echo "Creating: $OUTPUT"
  lipo -create $LIPO_CREATE -output $OUTPUT
  lipo -info $OUTPUT
done

echo "Copying headers from dist-$MAIN_ARCH..."
cp -R dist-$MAIN_ARCH/include/* $OUTPUT_DIR/include
```

then i import the .a files from BUILD-FOLDER/dist-uarch and it builds in xcode like a charm!

Comment: For the cputype error, please **make clean && make && make install** again. **make clean** does the trick